# Retention documents get lost when Content Organizer Rule is target to Drop Off Library

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, routes, retention

I found a strange behavior with SharePoint 2010 when it comes to Retention. I have a site with retention set up for a document library to route files to another site with a Drop Off Library. Everything seems to be working fine.
Now on to the destination site where my Drop Off Library is, normally you would have Content Organizer Rules to route your incoming documents, for testing purposes I have it routed to the same Drop Off Library, so it is kind of targeted to itself. The scary and potentially disastrous thing that happened next was that when the routing rules was activated by the timer job, the files got lost. Nothing at the recycle bin. No traces.

So the question is, is this normal? Do I simply need to have my routing rules target to another folder and this deleting out of nowhere wouldn't happen again? I have very important documents that needs archiving. I just want the possibility of them getting lost in thin air to be absolutely 0%. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is how the drop-off library works, you cannot target the drop-off library itself. Just create a test list on the same site as the target drop-off library and route the document there (to see if your rules work as expected)